# Trigonometric equation application

Tags: trigonometry

Find all values of $x$ between 0 and 4 for which $\sin(2x+1) = \cos (2x+1) $

I made the equation to become -

$$\tan (2x+1) = 1$$

Which I believe is correct.

Now the problem is , the range .

If the range is $0$ to $2\pi$ I would've known how to do but what about the $0$ to $4$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is in the interval $(0,4)$, what values does $2x+1$ take on?  How does the interval $[0,2\pi]$ compare to this set of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use that $$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=-\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-x\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi$ be the smallest value greater than $0$ such that $\tan\phi=1$.  Let $\theta$ be the smallest value greater than $0$ such that $\tan(\phi+\theta)=1$.  $\tan$ is periodic, and $\theta$ is the length of this period, so we only need to find the first value and the number of values of $\phi+n\theta$ that occur within the interval specified by $2x+1$ for $x\in(0,4)$.

The interval transformation is easy, we get $(1,9)$.  Then we have to compare $\phi=\frac {\pi}4$ and $\theta=\pi$ with this interval, and we get a first value of $\phi+\theta=\frac 54\pi$.  What should the total number of values be?

Further hint: you can use that $3\lt\pi\lt 4$ and $6\lt2\pi\lt 7$.